# NFS mapping a disabled account

Tags: nfs

Does Linux (non-AD joined) care if a mapped NFS users account is disabled in Active Directory?

For instance, I have an AD user account mapped in NFS to a Linux mount point. When I disabled that user account in AD, everything still works. Of course, when I delete that same user account in AD, access fails.

Does NFS access to the Linux mount point only relate to the UID mapping (irrespective of the accounts status in AD)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is Linux meant to access the account status in AD if it is not joined to the domain? Unless it is in the domain, or otherwise told to look to the domain for authentication, all it knows about is its own user database. So yes, NFS access to the mount point will depend only on the user credentials within Linux, unless you've established some way for that non-member Linux machine to query the AD DC for authentication. Which generally does mean the UID mapping, and the user credentials for that UID.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. 

So, in my scenario: AD domain account <--maps to --> GID 1234 (on storage platform acting as NFS server) <--maps to --> GID 1234 (Linux file server acting as NFS client)

-and therefore, only the SAM name (from AD side) is being used in this mapping. So, not even the account password in AD is being used for the NFS session authToken.

Do I have that right?

Comment: The Linux NFS session can be told to use the Kerberos authentication from the AD DC, there are hooks in PAM that support that, but unless you have explicitly done that, in fact it is the SAM name and (presumably) the stored password for the NFS share that are being used to authenticate against the Linux local database for the mapped UID. So you're right in outline at least. My own experience (running a Sendmail system against a Samba AD DC for authentication) is that a disabled account in the DC does not allow access to the mail server.